# Installing Kubuntu as solo boot

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu right now, and after advising want to try Kubuntu. I'd like to totally format previous OS and make Kubuntu running as solo boot. Is that possible? I've already downloaded kubuntu 14.04.2.iso and not sure how to do it.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

**There is only difference of desktop environment in Ubuntu and Kubuntu.**

**You can use Kde desktop environment in Ubuntu and turn it into Kubuntu** , you dont need to remove Ubuntu

Open terminal by pressing Crtl + Alt + T and then execute following command one by one :

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install software-properties-kde

sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

**If you still want to remove Ubuntu and Install Kubuntu.**

Burn iso image(kubuntu 14.04.2.iso ) into a DVD and [Visit this site for step by step process of installing Ubuntu (or Kubuntu)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  (I would have answered the same)

Answer (score 0):

Burn the .iso to a DVD or to a USB using some USB iso burning tool( there is one mentioned in backtracks'g guide, I cant remember the name).
All you have to do is boot from the DVD then and "Replace Ubuntu with Kubuntu, wipe clean"